# Should my product types be changed from configurable so that child discounts can be applied?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, bundled-product, discount, special-price

**Issue:** I need child products to have a special price that does not inherit from the parent product.

**Details:** Currently I am using configurable products to list product options. We need to run a promotion where each child product is discount. My problem is that the discount amount is different per product. So, where child option one may be discounted by $0.50, child option two may be discounted by $2, and option three by $1. Out of the box Magento does not allow differing special prices for child options - they're all inherited.

Is there a solution for this or should I be using bundled or group products rather than configurable.

Example:
Yummy Water (Configurable Product with normal pricing and desired discount)

- 20 ml bottle - $1 - $0.50
- 1 L bottle - $5 - $2
- Case of 5 20 ml bottle - $4 - $1
- Case of 10 1 L bottle - $40 - $10

## ***EDIT***:

*In response to answer below:* I left this problem hanging but am forced to revisit it now. I've reviewed 3 extensions whose purpose is to apply simple product pricing to configurable products. One is open source but has not been updated recently and the other two are a bit pricey for not being certified developers - Yes, I have trust issues as well.

I'm considering removing the configurable products and making the simple products publicly viewable while creating sub-categories for each product type option but my concern here is SEO impact (seemingly duplicate content) and the impact on the user experience since the customer would then have to go through multiple categories to browse a single flavor as opposed to how they currently can find the flavor and simply choose their size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Yummy Water should have dropdown selections (configurable attributes), you should use configurable products. If you use grouped or bundle products, the packaging of the product changes completely (look into what grouped, bundle, etc. products are).

However, from looking at the configurable options of Yummy Water (20mL, 1L, case of 5 20mL, case of 10 1L), it looks like you might be able to split this into multiple products. You can either make them all into simple products, which will solve your problem, or 20mL/1L configurable product, separate "Case of 5 20mL" simple product, etc. for example.. I personally don't think these should be grouped into one config. product.

If you really need these to be one configurable product, check out one of the extensions for using simple prices for configurable products.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=simple+price&pl=0

Comment: I left this problem hanging but am forced to revisit it now. I agree that these probably should not be grouped together but from a user experience and SEO perspective I am not sure how to handle this. We could easily subcategorize the category so that ml, L, ml case, and L case are the parents of the relevant products but we've lost the ability for the customer to go straight to Yummy Water and select the product that they want while adding tons of (seemingly duplicate) content to the website.

Comment: My instinct was this all along. I have been trying to force a selectable (dropdown-type) option because I wanted all options for a flavor to be available from a single location. Other than that my obstacle is overcoming SEO issues as the descriptions, images, etc are mostly the same.

Comment: What configuration did you end up going for?

Comment: mostly due to SEO concerns we have not yet made any changes. We need to investigate that part of it further. Thankfully, some time is being bought by our marketing team playing nicely, for the time being, by going with discounts that can be applied to all options rather than a unique discount per item.

Answer (score 1):

> In response to answer below: I left this problem hanging but am forced to revisit it now. I've reviewed 3 extensions whose purpose is to apply simple product pricing to configurable products. One is open source but has not been updated recently and the other two are a bit pricey for not being certified developers - Yes, I have trust issues as well.

You probably missed [Better Configurable Products](http://www.nr-apps.com/store/bcp-better-configurable-products.html?utm_source=category.teaser&utm_campaign=BCP+-+Better+Configurable+Products) (349 €), originally developed by Vinai Kopp who is not only certified developer but member of the *Magento Certification Advisory Board*.

Truth be told, it is good code and I would prefer it over any other "simple configurable products" extension, but I would only use it if there is really no other option. There are quite a few class rewrites of important core classes, because the extension changes completely how the configurable product type works (but that's what you want, right?)

### How it works:

When you select options on the configurable products page, an AJAX request is triggered that internally renders the product page of the simple product and replaces parts of the page (you define the parts with CSS selectors in the configuration, so it works for any theme). Usually this is price, media gallery and description, but you can configure anything else, like upsell products or whatever.

When you put a configurable product in the cart, actually the simple product is added, so all price rules for the simple product apply

Answer (score 1):

> I've reviewed 3 extensions whose purpose is to apply simple product
>   pricing to configurable products.

Have you reviewed Ayasoftware_SimpleProductPricing extension? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-product-pricing.html

The extension supports special pricing, has high rating and costs $119.